# replace text file unix line endings to windows by using VBScripts

Tags: batch-file, unix, replace, cmd, vbscript

The text file new line is /n. When I open it with Notepad , it does not display the new line. It displays new line when I open it with Notepad++.

I create a VBscript to replace the new line with \r\n(Windows line endings) from \n(unix line endings).

The script does not work for replace the new lin. It works when I replace text from AAA to BBB:

What is replace expression to replace a new line? -Thanks

Can I use windows Command line CMD-seg to replace the new line ?

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\Replace_Text.txt",ForReading)

strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
strNewText = Replace(strText, "\n", "\r\n")

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\Replace_Text.txt",ForWriting)
objFile.WriteLine strNewText

objFile.Close
```

Comment: Does this help: `vbCr = "\r"`, `vbLf = "\n"`, `vbCrLf = "\r\n"`?

Comment: Incidentally, from [[tag:cmd]] or a [[tag:batch-file]], if you don't mind TABs replaced with SPACES you could just use `%SystemRoot%\System32\more.com "input.txt" 1>"output.txt"`, or if TABs are important `Type "input.txt" | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /V "" 1>"output.txt"`. Obviously in both cases, this isn't doing an inline replacement, so the output file would then need to replace the input file.

Comment: That’s two questions stick to one question you either want to do this in VBScript or use a batch-file not both. Either way it’s a duplicate, you not the first person to ask how to correct UNIX line endings on [so].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick example [vbscript](/questions/tagged/vbscript), besed upon my initial comment:

```vb
Option Explicit

Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Dim strTargetFile, objFSO, strText, strNewText, objFile

strTargetFile = "C:\Replace_Text.txt"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strTargetFile, ForReading)
strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close

strNewText = Replace(strText, vbLf, vbCrLf)

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strTargetFile, ForWriting)
objFile.WriteLine strNewText
objFile.Close

WScript.Quit
```

And a quick example [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), based upon my second comment:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

Set "TargetFile=C:\Replace_Text.txt"

Set "TempFile=%TargetFile%.tmp"
Copy /Y "%TargetFile%" "%TempFile%"
Type "%TempFile%" | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /V "" 1>"%TargetFile%"
If Not ErrorLevel 1 Del "%TempFile%"
```

Comment: Hi Compo, Thanks. It works. I accepts it as solution.

Comment: Hi Compo, Can we change multiple text files in the same folder, such as Change all text files in c:\test folder?

Comment: Yes you can. You could start by getting the folder using the file system object, you've already defined, e.g. `Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\wherever")`, then you could enumerate each of the files in contains, using for example, `For Each objFile In objFolder.Files`, perform your replacements, then use the line `Next` before your `WScript.Quit` command. It may be better to use a `Sub` containing your replacement code, and call that `Sub` in your `For Each`. As that is an additional question, unrelated to your submitted one, I'll leave it to you to put it together.